# Special case quintic equation analytic solution

Tags: quintics

I've met this quintic equation in my research:
$$x^5 - \frac{k}{k-1} \cdot x^3 +\frac{r}{k-1}=0$$
with the additional conditions:
$$k>1; \quad 0<r<1; \quad 0<x<1$$
My background in math is limited. I know that it cannot be solved in radicals, but can be using the elliptic functions. However, elliptic function method requires transforming the equation to the Bring-Jerrard form. 
I just wondered if it is possible to find a analytic solution easier way.
Basically, I need just one function x(r,k) in real positive number which satisfies the equation. Is it possible? How to get one?

Comment: There may be up to five real solutions. Have you  tried using power series?

Comment: When using numerical solutions for the equation with $k$ and $r$ values in sensible range, as they are measured physically, I've got 3 real solutions and 2 of them positive, and only one of them satisfies condition $0<x<1$

I've tried using method from the paper _"Polynomial Transformations of Tschirnhaus, Bring and Jerrard"_  by Victor S. Adamchik and David J. Jeffrey and remove the $x^3$ term. However it caused the $x^2$ and $x$ terms to appear and solution became quite clumsy. I hope there is a simpler and less laborious way.

Comment: If this helps, by inverting the unknown, $x^5+ax^3+b$ can be rewritten $y^5+py^2+q$.

Comment: Can't you do with $r(x,k)$ or $k(x,r)$ ?

Comment: Unfortunatly, no. I need $x(r,k)$ because $r$ and $k$ are measurable values and $x$ can be only calculated from model and in this case from the equation. $x$ value is important for my research as it used in decision making.

Comment: By [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), this has 2 or 4 positive zeros (if the coefficients written are positive).

Comment: For trinomial with one parameter (as in answer below) work perfect hypergeometric formulas Mellin/Lagrange (see [Belardinelli, p.56, formulas (4) and (5)](http://www.numdam.org/item/MSM_1960__145__1_0/)), and [formula by Лахтинъ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206420/is-it-a-mistake-in-the-formula-or-inaccuracy-in-the-calculations-of-numerical-in) with definite integration

Answer (score 1):

Writing $x = (r/(k-1))^{1/5} y$, the equation becomes
$$ y^5 - \frac{k}{(k-1)^{3/5} r^{2/5}} y^3+ 1 = 0$$
Let $c = k/((k-1)^{3/5} r^{2/5}$, so this is 
$y^5 - c y^3 + 1 = 0$.

Now, if you want a solution with $y > 0$, $c$ must not be too small.  If $c > 0$, the minimum value of $y^5 - c y^3 + 1$ for $y \ge 0$ is $1 - 6 \sqrt{15} c^{5/2}/125$, and you want that $\le 0$, so you need
$$c \ge \frac{5 \cdot 2^{3/5} \cdot 3^{2/5}}{6}$$
If $c$ is greater than this, there will be two positive real solutions for $y$ (and thus for $x$), if $c$ is less there will be none.